# Parent redirect when using iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I know there are several questions/answers already about how to redirect a parent window from within an iframe, but this one has a slight twist.

I need to be able to redirect the parent window when the page in the iframe is changed. However, the page in the iframe is not on my domain, so I can't use the parent.window.location trick that was suggested in other threads.

So, for example, if I put stackoverflow.com in my iframe, I need the parent frame to redirect when the user clicks any link on the stackoverflow page.

I doubt this is actually possible, but I thought there might be some sort of polling of the iframe that the parent can do or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit convoluted, but should do the trick. If you define your IFRAME like this

```
<iframe id="xMyIframe" src="http://someurl" onload="replaceLoad(this)" ></iframe>
```

Then you can define a JavaScript code;

```
function replaceLoad(oIframe) {
  oIframe.onload = function () {
     location.href = 'http://www.microsfot.com'
  }
}
```

On load of the initial Iframe URL inital `onload` event handler fires which replaces itself with new handler that will fire after next load i.e. after user clicks link in the iframed page.

Comment: This is great. However, the URL I redirect the parent to is based upon the URL that the iFrame is going to, so instead of using location.href = "microsoft.com" I need to use something like location.ref = oIframe.location.href. Unfortunately, that doesn't work, any idea what the proper way for that would be?

Comment: Also, the way this is done it loads the new page in the iframe, THEN redirects the parent. Is there any alternative to the "onload" event that would make the parent redirect happen first?

Comment: You can use `location.href = oIframe.src` to use iframe source URL. Have to look into "before" possibilities

Comment: Also, do you need your redirect URL based on original iframe source or the new one that it gets after user click?

Comment: I was just going to ask about that. oIframe.src gives the current URL, but I need the one it's going to.

Comment: That I am afraid is not possible cross-domain due to security reasons